# Linearity of Variance and Expected value

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

I know Expected value has the property of linearity $E(X+a)=E(X) + a$, but it also seems to hold for $E(X^3+a)$. But Variance also has the property $V(X+a)=V(X) + 0$, but it does not hold for $V(X^3+a)=V(X^3) + 0$.

I discovered this from a question that asked to find the expected value adn variance for $Y = X^3 + 2$ given a distribution for $X$.

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline x&-1&0&1&2\\\hline p(x)&0.1&0.4&0.3&0.2\\\hline\end{array}$$

[image: table]

The table shows the distribution for $X$, so I worked out $E(Y) = E(X^3 - 2) = 1.8 - 2 =-0.2$.

For variance I am thinking $V(Y) = V(X^3 - 2) = E(X^{3\times2}) - E(X^3)^2 - 0 =E(X^6)-0.2^2$ from which I get 11.16

Comment: It does hold.   $X^3$ is a random variable, and $V(Z+a)=V(Z)$ holds for any random variable $Z$ and constant $a$.  $$V(X^3+2)=V(X^3)$$  If you add some of your working, we can help find where you went awry.

Comment: Ok, I will add the question information then

Comment: I suspect the $E(X^6)$ is wrong?

Comment: Yes.  Why did you square the $X^3$ term when applying Linearity?  It should be $$\mathsf V(aZ+b)=a^2\mathsf V(Z) + 0$$You only square the coefficient (when you distribute out of the variance) not the random variable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write my working out properly. I've updated - it should've been $E(X^6)$ - is that correct?

Comment: Nevermind I see your post answer and see that I was correct (phew). I wonder where I went wrong then. Ill try punching it into the calculator again

Comment: Yes, that is better.  But you indicated that $\mathsf E(X^3)=1.8$, not $0.2$

Comment: Yes I see where I went wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of variance and the Linearity of Expectation:$$\begin{align}\mathsf V(X^3+a) &= \mathsf E((X^3+a)^2)-(\mathsf E(X^3+a))^2 \\ &= \mathsf E(X^6+2aX^3+a^2)-(\mathsf E(X^3)+a)^2\\ &=\bigl(\mathsf E(X^6)+2a\mathsf E(X^3)+a^2\bigr)-\bigl(\mathsf E(X^3)^2+2a\mathsf E(X^3)+a^2\bigr)\\&=\mathsf E(X^6)-\mathsf E(X^3)^2\\&=\mathsf V (X^3)\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline x&-1&0&1&2\\\hline p(x)&0.1&0.4&0.3&0.2\\\hline\end{array}$$

$\mathsf E(X^3) = -1\cdot 0.1+1\cdot 0.3+0+2^3\cdot 0.2 = 1.8\\\mathsf E(X^6) = 1\cdot(0.1+0.3)+2^6\cdot0.2 = 13.2\\\mathsf {V}(X^3)= 13.2-1.8^2 = 9.96$

Comment: I think I see where I went wrong! I used $E(Y)^2$ for $E(X^3)^2$ which was very wrong! Problem solved!